# Order of Operators - Question in Proof of Abel's Transformation - Summation by Parts

Tags: recurrence-relations, summation-by-parts

Given a sequence $\left(a_n \right)$, the operators $\Delta, E$ are defined by $$\Delta a_n=a_{n+1}-a_n,\\Ea_n=a_{n+1}.$$

Let $\left(u_n \right)$ and $\left(v_n \right)$ be two sequences. Let $\Delta_1, E_1$ denote the restriction of $\Delta, E$ to $u_n$, and let $\Delta_2, E_2$ denote the restriction of $\Delta, E$ to $v_n$.

In the proof of Abel's transformation (page 21 of *Finite Difference Equations, 1st Ed. by H. Levy and F. Lessman*), they write

$$\Delta \left(u_n v_n\right)=u_{n+1}\Delta_{2}v_n+v_n\Delta_{1}u_n=\left(E_{1}\Delta_{2}+\Delta_{1}\right)u_n v_n.$$

Then the authors simplify this as

$$\Delta \left(u_n v_n\right)=E_1 \color{green}{\Delta_2} \left(1+\color{blue}{E_{1}^{-1}\Delta_{1}\Delta_{2}^{-1}}\right)u_nv_n. \tag{$1$}$$

- **Does the order of the operators in the expression** $\color{blue}{E_{1}^{-1}\Delta_{1}\Delta_{2}^{-1}}$
  **matter?** [I think yes, in general, but perhaps not in this case because the $\color{green}{\Delta_2}$ outside of the parentheses will destroy any constant that appears upon replacing $E_{1}^{-1}\Delta_{1}\Delta_{2}^{-1}$ with any operator formed by reordering the three operators.]

From $(1)$, we have

$$\Delta ^{-1} \left(u_n v_n\right)=\frac{E_{1}^{-1}\Delta_{2}^{-1}}{1+E_{1}^{-1}\Delta_1 \Delta_{2}^{-1}}u_n v_n, \tag{$2$}$$

and then they operate on both sides of $(2)$ with $1+E_{1}^{-1}\Delta_1 \Delta_{2}^{-1}$ to obtain

$$\Delta^{-1} \left(u_{n}v_{n} \right) = \left(E_{1}^{-1}\Delta_{2}^{-1}-\color{red}{\Delta^{-1}\Delta_{1}E_{1}^{-1}\Delta_{2}^{-1}}\right)u_n v_n. \tag{$3$}$$

- **In** $(3)$, **how do they get the** $\color{red}{\Delta^{-1}\Delta_{1}E_{1}^{-1}\Delta_{2}^{-1}}$ **term?** [I get $E_{1}^{-1}\Delta_{1}\Delta_{2}^{-1}\Delta^{-1}.$]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First question:** Does the order of the operators in the expression $\color{blue}{E_{1}^{-1}\Delta_{1}\Delta_{2}^{-1}}$ matter? The answer is no, it does not matter.

- The operators $\Delta,\Delta_1,\Delta_2,E,E_1,E_2$ are linear. We have for instance
  \begin{align*}
  \Delta_1\left(cu_n+du_m\right)&= c\left(u_{n+1}-u_n\right)+d\left(u_{m+1}-u_m\right)\\
  &=c\Delta_1 \left(u_n\right)+d\Delta_1 \left(u_m\right)
  \end{align*}
  where c,d are constant values and linearity can be similarly shown for the other operators.
- The operators $E_1^{-1}$ and $\Delta_1$ commute. We obtain
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{\left(E_1^{-1}\Delta_1\right)}\left(u_nv_n\right)&=v_n\left(E_1^{-1}\Delta_1\right)\left(u_n\right)\tag{1.1}\\
  &=v_nE_1^{-1}\left(u_{n+1}-u_n\right)\\
  &=v_n\left(u_n-u_{n-1}\right)\tag{1.2}\\
  &=v_n\Delta_1\left(u_{n-1}\right)\\
  &=v_n\Delta_1E_1^{-1}u_n\\
  &\,\,\color{blue}{=\left(\Delta_1E_1^{-1}\right)}\left(u_nv_n\right)\tag{1.1}
  \end{align*}
  and commutativity follows. In (1.1) we use the linearity of the operators $\Delta_1$ and $E_1$, since due to the restriction of these operators the other sequence elements $v_n$ are considered to be constants.

Now we want to calculate $E_1^{-1}\Delta_1\Delta_2^{-1}$ and $\Delta_2^{-1}E_1^{-1}\Delta_1$. We recall the following identities
\begin{align*}
\Delta_2^{-1}\left(v_n\right)&=\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}v_r+c&\text{c const.}\tag{2.1}\\
\Delta_2\Delta_2^{-1}\left(v_n\right)&=v_n&\text{per def.}\\
\Delta_2^{-1}\Delta_2\left(v_n\right)&=v_n+d&\text{d const.}\\
\end{align*}

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> &\color{blue}{\left(E_1^{-1}\Delta_1\Delta_2^{-1}\right)\left(u_nv_n\right)}\\
> &\qquad=\left(E_1^{-1}\Delta_1\right)\Delta_2^{-1}\left(u_nv_n\right)\\
> &\qquad=\left(E_1^{-1}\Delta_1\right) u_n\left(\Delta_2^{-1}\left(v_n\right)\right)\tag{$\to$ linearity}\\
> &\qquad=\left(E_1^{-1}\Delta_1\right) \left(u_n\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}v_r+c\right)\right)\tag{$\to$ (2.1)}\\
> &\qquad=\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}v_r+c\right)\left(E_1^{-1}\Delta_1\right) \left(u_n\right)\tag{$\to$ linearity}\\
> &\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{=\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}v_r+c\right)\left(u_n-u_{n-1}\right)}\tag{$\to$ (1.2)}\\
> \\
> &\color{blue}{\left(\Delta_2^{-1}E_1^{-1}\Delta_1\right)\left(u_nv_n\right)}\\
> &\qquad=\Delta_2^{-1}\left(\left(E_1^{-1}\Delta_1\right)\left(u_nv_n\right)\right)\\
> &\qquad=\Delta_2^{-1} v_n\left(E_1^{-1}\Delta_1\right)\left(u_n\right)\tag{$\to$ linearity}\\
> &\qquad=\left(\Delta_2^{-1}\right)\left( v_n\left(u_n-u_{n-1}\right)\right)\tag{$\to$ (1.2)}\\
> &\qquad=\left(u_n-u_{n-1}\right)\left(\Delta_2^{-1}\right)\left( v_n\right)\tag{$\to$ linearity}\\
> &\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{=\left(u_n-u_{n-1}\right)\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}v_r+c\right)}\tag{$\to$ (2.1)}\\
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

**Second question:** In $(3)$, how do they get the $\color{red}{\Delta^{-1}\Delta_{1}E_{1}^{-1}\Delta_{2}^{-1}}$ term? [I get $E_{1}^{-1}\Delta_{1}\Delta_{2}^{-1}\Delta^{-1}$]. Here are some aspects. The operator identity stated in (2)
\begin{align*}
\Delta ^{-1}=\frac{E_{1}^{-1}\Delta_{2}^{-1}}{1+E_{1}^{-1}\Delta_1 \Delta_{2}^{-1}}
\end{align*}
indicates, that *both*, multiplication from the left-hand side as well as multiplication from the right-hand side with
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1+E_{1}^{-1}\Delta_1 \Delta_{2}^{-1}}=\left(1+E_{1}^{-1}\Delta_1 \Delta_{2}^{-1}\right)^{-1}\tag{3.1}
\end{align*}
is admissible. In (3) we have multiplication from the right-hand side. We obtain from (3)
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\Delta^{-1}}&\color{blue}{=E_1^{-1}\Delta_2^{-1}-\Delta^{-1}\Delta_1E_1^{-1}\Delta_2^{-1}}\\
\Delta^{-1}+\Delta^{-1}\Delta_1E_1^{-1}\Delta_2^{-1}&=E_1^{-1}\Delta_2^{-1}\\
\Delta^{-1}\left(1+\Delta_1E_1^{-1}\Delta_2^{-1}\right)&=E_1^{-1}\Delta_2^{-1}\\
\Delta\Delta^{-1}\left(1+\Delta_1E_1^{-1}\Delta_2^{-1}\right)&=\Delta E_1^{-1}\Delta_2^{-1}\\
\color{blue}{1+\Delta_1E_1^{-1}\Delta_2^{-1}}&\color{blue}{=\Delta E_1^{-1}\Delta_2^{-1}}\tag{4.1}\\
\end{align*}

We check the validity of (4.1) by evaluating left-hand side and right-hand side at $u_nv_n$.

> We obtain from the left-hand side of (4.1)
> \begin{align*}
> &\color{blue}{\left(1+\Delta_1E_1^{-1}\Delta_2^{-1}\right)(u_nv_n)}\\
> &\qquad=u_nv_n+\left(\Delta_1E_1^{-1}\right)(u_n)\left(\Delta_2^{-1}\left(v_n\right)\right)\tag{$\to$ linearity}\\
> &\qquad =u_nv_n+\left(\Delta_1E_1^{-1}\right)(u_n)\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}v_r+c\right)\tag{$\to$ (2.1)}\\
> &\qquad =u_nv_n+\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}v_r+c\right)\left(\Delta_1E_1^{-1}\right)(u_n)\tag{$\to$ linearity}\\
> &\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{=u_nv_n+\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}v_r+c\right)\left(u_n-u_{n-1}\right)}\tag{$\to$ (1.2)}\\
> \end{align*}
> and from the right-hand side
> \begin{align*}
> &\color{blue}{\left(\Delta E_1^{-1}\Delta_2^{-1}\right)\left(u_nv_n\right)}\\
> &\qquad=\Delta E_1^{-1}\left(u_n\right)\Delta_2^{-1}\left(v_n\right)\tag{$\to$ linearity}\\
> &\qquad=\Delta E_1^{-1}\left(u_n\right)\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}v_r+c\right)\tag{$\to$ (2.1)}\\
> &\qquad=\Delta \left(\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}v_r+c\right)E_1^{-1}\left(u_n\right)\tag{$\to$ linearity}\\
> &\qquad=\Delta \left(\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}v_r+c\right)u_{n-1}\\
> &\qquad=\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n}v_r+c\right)u_{n}-\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}v_r+c\right)u_{n-1}\tag{$\to \Delta$}\\
> &\qquad\color{blue}{=u_nv_n+\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}v_r+c\right)\left(u_n-u_{n-1}\right)}
> \end{align*}
> showing the validity of (4.1).

**Note:** Not part of the answer, but a nice symmetry which follows from OPs stated product formula at the beginning:
\begin{align*}
\Delta \left(u_n v_n\right)=u_{n+1}\Delta_{2}v_n+v_n\Delta_{1}u_n=\left(E_{1}\Delta_{2}+\Delta_{1}\right)u_n v_n
\end{align*}
Since $\Delta\left(u_n v_n\right)=\Delta\left(v_n u_n\right)$ and since $E_1=\Delta_1+1$ and $E_2=\Delta_2+1$ we have
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\Delta}&=E_{1}\Delta_{2}+\Delta_{1}\\
&=E_2\Delta_1+\Delta_2\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\Delta_1+\Delta_2+\Delta_1\Delta_2}
\end{align*}

Comment: @TheSubstitute: Many thanks for accepting my answer and granting the bounty. :-)